# google Drive api v3 file upload errors

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

The google drive api on python is showing the following error. My file upload code is already mentioned on  [Google Drive api v3 file upload errors via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587769/google-drive-api-v3-file-upload-errors-via-python)

I am getting the following errors,

```
 File "/opt/cppython/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1685, in _request
    raise RedirectMissingLocation(
httplib2.RedirectMissingLocation: Redirected but the response is missing a Location: header.
```

My pips are as follows,

```
google-api-core          1.22.4
google-api-python-client 1.12.3
google-auth              1.22.1
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.1
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0
httplib2                 0.18.1
```

I am using python 3.8.6 . Some old posts say it need to downgrade  some packages. But I hope this will be some other issues.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Can you provide your current script for replicating the error of `Redirected but the response is missing a Location: header.`? Because when I tested your script in [your link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64587769), I confirmed the error of `Bad Request` which is not `Redirected but the response is missing a Location: header.`.

Comment: Now I noticed that you had answered for your question. I apologize for this. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been solved by  modifying the following connection code too google drive api.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('json-file', SCOPES)
http=Http()
http.redirect_codes = http.redirect_codes - {308}
http_auth = credentials.authorize(http)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth,cache_discovery=False)
```